# Sliding Nav Arrow

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, navigation

I'm trying to create a sliding arrow at the very top of my header that slides horizontally in accordance with the currently active menu item.

EDIT - the website I was referring to as an example is no longer active.

The arrow should be in the correct position when the page loads up (i.e. directly above the active menu item). Currently, my effort has it sliding in from the left hand side of the screen before coming to rest above the active button when the page loads/refreshes.

I'm currently using jQuery 1.8.3, Modernizr and Cycle Lite on my site for various other functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following fiddle, demonstrates as much as I understand you are looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/8DZZQ/13/

The following is the jsfiddle javascript. In this, I've adjusted the nav_arrow using margins, but you could just as easily have it positioned absolutely and move it based on the offsetLeft of the options.

The arrangement function, arr(), is added to the mouseover and mouseout events, meaning that the new location of the nav_arrow can be calculated, and the margin adjusted accordingly, with the default option being sent by mouseout in order for the arrow to spring back by default.

Each menu item has had the property default added to it, in order for an onclick event to change which item becomes the default to come back to - though this assumes your links are dynamic and that the page doesn't reload/change to another page, if thats the case then you should just alter which div has the id="d" to the appropriate item on the different page's html and adjust the code accordingly.

I've also added a finetuning array, so you can position your arrow over each div to the precise point you like. The values are added onto the left position of each menu item, so for link1 say, its width is 60ish and with padding/margins etc a fine tuning of 34 placing the nav_arrow over the centre:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var fine = [36, 34, 34, 34];
    var mitms = document.getElementsByClassName('mitm');
    var l0 = (mitms[0].offsetLeft + fine[0]);
    document.getElementById("nav_arrow").style.marginLeft = l0 + "px";

    for (var i = 0; i < mitms.length; i++) {
        mitms[i].default = false;
        mitms[i].fine = fine[i];
        mitms[i].onmouseover = function () {arr(this);};
        mitms[i].onmouseout = function () {
            var tmp = document.getElementsByClassName('mitm');
            for (var j=0; j<tmp.length; j++) {
                if (tmp[j].default === true) {arr(tmp[j]); break;}
            }
        };
        mitms[i].onclick = function() {
            var tmp = document.getElementsByClassName('mitm');
            for (var j=0; j<tmp.length; j++) {tmp[j].default = false;}
            this.default = true;
        }
    }
    mitms[0].default = true;
};

function arr(el) {
    var mitms = document.getElementsByClassName('mitm');
    var l = el.offsetLeft + el.fine;
    document.getElementById("nav_arrow").style.marginLeft = l + "px";
}
```

The html is similar to the example site you gave:

```
<div id="nav">
    <div id="d" class="mitm"><a href="#">Default</a></div>
    <div class="mitm"><a href="#">Link1</a></div>
    <div class="mitm"><a href="#">Link2</a></div>
    <div class="mitm"><a href="#">Link3</a></div>
    <div id="nav_arrow"></div>
</div>
```

With the smooth transitions being covered by the css:

```
#nav_arrow {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;

  /* Gets you your triangle, no image needed */
  background: transparent;
  border-left: 7px solid transparent; 
  border-right: 7px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #000;
  border-bottom: none;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  font-size: 1px;

  /* Transitions to give smooth movement*/
  transition: margin 1s;
  -moz-transition: margin 1s; /* Firefox 4 */
  -webkit-transition: margin 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transition: margin 1s; /* Opera */
  /* IE doesn't support until ie10 */
}
```

As IE doesn't yet support css transitions, I'm sure there will be an appropriate jquery solution for making IE transitions smooth.

Hope helps!

**Edit!**

This is also possible with simply css using the likes of:

```
#menuitem1:hover ~ #nav_arrow {
   margin: 0px 0px 0px 185px;
}
```

assuming menuitem1 is

```
<a id='menuitem1'></a>
```

and using transitions as before etc.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Almost exactly what I'm looking for. I've managed to adapt your code for my site. A couple of things have me stumped, however:
1) After clicking a button, the 'active' button needs to become the default so the arrow stays over it after it's clicked - as on the site I referenced. Any ideas on how to get this working?
2) Do you know of a slightly more precise way to set the position of the arrow? You mentioned something about positioning absolutely and moving it based on the offsetLeft of the options. I'm not 100% sure what you mean. Might that be the way forward for me? - Leon

Comment: The fine tuning array works beautifully, thank you. However, I'm having trouble with the default element situation. My buttons are not dynamic and the page does change/refresh when a button is clicked. I already have some javascript code that dynamically assigns a class to a button after it's clicked and the page reloads. Are you able to advise on how I can modify your code to treat an element with said class as the default to point to when the page loads and to snap back to on mouseout? I've tried substituting 'mitm' for my 'active_class' at various points without any luck.

Comment: Additionally, I've just noticed that each instance of "default" in the javascript code is causing IE8 to throw a hissy-fit. I'm thinking that if I can use my 'active_class' to denote the default button, then the portions of code involving "default" may not be necessary. Would this be a sensible assumption? Sorry for all the questions - my knowledge of javascript is rudimentary at best.

Comment: I eventually managed to get this working following a fair bit of background reading and some tweaking of the code you provided. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I just want to say, this is a damn impressive answer. Well done CJ!