# jquery slide on mousover + stay active on select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working navigation and I want to add some animation when mouse is over a link a shape arrow below would slide to that link and stay active when page is activated

here is an example
[image: screenshot of example]

navigation code

```
<nav>
<ul>
<li><span id="arrow"></span><a class="home" href=""><i class="material-icons nav-icon-home">home</i></a></li>
<li><a id="a-b" href=""><i class="material-icons nav-icon">build</i>SERVICES</a></li>
<li><a id="a-c" href=""><i class="material-icons nav-icon">people</i>ABOUT US</a></li>
<li><a id="a-d" href=""><i class="material-icons nav-icon">email</i>CONTACT US</a></li>
<li><a id="a-e" href=""><i class="material-icons nav-icon">work</i>CAREERS</a></li>
</ul>
```

arrow css code

```
#arrow {
position: absolute;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-left: 10px solid transparent;
border-right: 10px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 10px solid #FFFFFF;
top: 55px;
z-index: 100;
}
```

I just need help on the jquery part any ideas how to go about to get this working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sliding Nav Arrow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15229757/sliding-nav-arrow) which has [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8DZZQ/13/) that goes along with what you want

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('nav ul li').hover(function(){ 

  $('#arrow').stop().animate({ 
     left: $(this).offset().left+'px'
   }, 300, function() {
     // Animation complete.
   }); 

},function(){

  $('#arrow').stop().animate({ 
     left: $('nav ul li').eq(0).offset().left+'px'
   }, 300, function() {
     // Animation complete.
   });

});
```

Answer (score -1):

check it

```js
$('nav ul li').hover(function(){ 

  $('#arrow').offset({left:$(this).offset().left});

},function(){

  $('#arrow').offset({left:$('nav ul li').eq(0).offset().left});

});
```

Comment: Please, explain your answer.[From review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/10627632).